# How can I define three environment variables time date and timezone and then also convert the timezone to UTC in python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pymongo

I wanted to create three environment variables with date time and timezone and then convert the date to timezone UTC

```py
Var= Date time.date time.strptime(date,time,timezone, “%d%m%Y %H%M%S %z)
```

it doesn’t work

Also environment variables values are not accessible through .env file it show none value. How do I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I created a `datetime.datetime` object using date, time, and timezone info, using Python 3.10.11. To convert the information of these 3 variables, you first need to assign them to a single string which will then be parsed. Does this help?

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
    
date = "2023/05/09"
time = "11:20"
timezone = "+0200"
    
time_string = f"{date} {time} {timezone}"
    
var = datetime.strptime(time_string, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M %z")
var_utc = var.astimezone(tz=timezone.utc)

print(var)  # 2023-05-09 11:20:00-08:00
```

Update: New code snippet based on questions of OP

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timezone

# setting date, time, timezone as environmental variables
os.environ["DATE"] = "2023/05/09"
os.environ["TIME"] = "11:20"
os.environ["TIMEZONE"] = "-0800"  # -0800 is UTC offset for Pacific Time Zone

time_string = f"{os.environ['DATE']} {os.environ['TIME']} {os.environ['TIMEZONE']}"

var = datetime.strptime(time_string, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M %z")
var_utc = var.astimezone(tz=timezone.utc)

print(var)  # 2023-05-09 11:20:00-08:00
print(var_utc)  # 2023-05-09 19:20:00+00:00
```

Comment: Are these environmen variables?

Comment: Can I use in PST in timezone?

Comment: Hi @Amna! These are not environmental variables. Let me add another example which answers your questions.

Comment: I have tried this and it works I have included logging (var_utc)  but error I got is module is not callable why is it so?

Comment: Hi Amna! It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you are using with `logging`. However, I understand that you are doing something like `import logging` and then `logging('Hello World')` which raises this error (in the example I mentioned it should be `logging.warning('Hello World')`). The official documentation features a useful introductory tutorial of using [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example Python 3 script that shows how to convert a date/time/timezone to UTC:

```py
from datetime import datetime, UTC

date = "2023-05-09"
time = "11:20"
timezone = "+0200"

date_time = datetime.fromisoformat(f"{date} {time} {timezone}")
utc_string = date_time.astimezone(UTC).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

print(utc_string) # 2023-05-09 09:20
```

Comment: Also it raises error invalid isoformat string